# Add a child `div` component on button click (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a child `div` component (div-col inside of div-row) on the click of the button. Like here I am trying to change the orientation of the cards from the grid to list view. I am using the bootstrap inbuilt class here.

If it is `grid view`, then

```html
<div className="row">
  {notes.map((item, key) => {
    return <Noteitem  />;
  })}
</div>
```

if the `listview` button is clicked

```html
<div className="row">
  <div className="col"> 
    {notes.map((item, key) => {
      return <Noteitem  />;
    })}
  </div> 
</div>
```

Do I need to use return the DOM for both separately?? Or welcome for any other approach also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create state `myView` and set default to 'GridView'
listView button is clicked, setState to 'ListView'.

use this state, render like

```js
{
  myView === "GridView" ? (
    <div className="row">
        {notes.map((item, key) => {
          return <Noteitem />;
        })}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col">
        {notes.map((item, key) => {
          return <Noteitem />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Bee answer, but a bit more succinct and fleshed out:

```
const [grid, setGrid] = useState(false)

return (
    <button onClick={() => setGrid(!grid)} />
    <div className="row">
       <div className={grid ? "col" : ""}> 
         {notes.map((item, key) => {
            return <Noteitem  />;
         })}
      </div> 
    </div>
)
```

##### Explanation

You keep the `div` element on the DOM and just change the `className` to and from `col` or nullish.  Use the `onClick` attribute on your button to toggle the grid view on and off. Keep the state value as a Boolean so that you can reference its truthy/falsey value directly using a ternary operator to assign the `className` value to the `div`.

Comment: Nice approach but the nullish div component is also considered as a `col` class component. Thank you for your help :)